# Why does my C++ compiled Windows .exe have .h source code in it?

Tags: windows, qt, exe

I've been making an application in Qt (highly recommended for quick GUI-centric applications).  I'm compiling with Microsoft Visual C++ 15.0 in Qt.  Everything works fine, just wondering why the resulting .exe has one of the header files fully pasted in the middle of the program with line breaks and everything.  Has anyone experienced this or heard of this?  I can't find one reason why this would happen.  Something to do with my includes maybe?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that. Are you sure you don't have that .h listed in the [resources](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html)? Does the issue appear only when using MSVC? If so, Does a simple visual studio application (one that does not use Qt) exhibit the same issue?

Comment: Did you include it as a resource? If so that's expected; resources are for bundling any type of arbitrary file (usually graphics, etc.) inside the executable file.

Comment: I'm impressed. How did you find out about this? I'm building exe's every day, debug, and test them but I cannot remember when I last hex-dumped one (and if so, why)...

Comment: Thank you both, it was included as a resource!  I was viewing the hex-dump because I was researching storing data at the end of an exe.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.h was included as a resource.  Thanks to Mike and MrEricSir.